# Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{3n+n(-1)^n}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I have to find out if the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{3n+n(-1)^n}$$ converges. Root test and ratio test did not work out for me. I also tried the alternating series test, but I can not use it because of the $${(-1)^{n+1}}$$ in the denominator.
Also, I have to find the limit of the series if it does converge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By observation, the series diverges. In order to prove it diverges, it is sufficient to prove it by proving the grouped series diverges.
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{3n+n(-1)^n}\text{ diverges if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3(2n-1)-(2n-1)}-\frac{1}{3\cdot 2n+2n}$diverges.}\\
$$But we have$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3(2n-1)-(2n-1)}-\frac{1}{3\cdot 2n+2n}\\
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2 n+1}{8 n (2 n-1)}=+\infty$$

Comment: Thank yo for your helpful answer. However, I have trouble understanding if I am allowed to group the terms, because in my opinion this way, I rearrange the summands and there is a theorem that says:

 If ∑∞n=1an is an absolutely convergent series to the sum s, then any rearrangement of the terms of this series will also converge to the sum s. If ∑∞n=1an is a conditionally convergent series to the sum s, then the terms of this series can be rearranged to converge to any s∈R or to diverge to ±∞.

So how can I be sure I didn't make it divergent by rearranging it?

Comment: @Niko No, grouping is not like rearranging. It is allowed to group terms in convergent series. Try to prove the series diverge By using contraction.

Comment: Okay, I didn't know that. Thanks. But you say I am allowed to group terms in _convergent_ series. But at the beginning, I don't know whether this one is convergent... So am I allowed anyway to group terms?

Comment: @Niko Assume it is convergent, the grouped series is convergent. But the grouped one is actually divergent. Hence the original one is not convergent.

Comment: Sorry, the contraction in above is actually conflict. I'm not so good at English :(

Comment: Oh no problem, I got the idea :)
Could you explain briefly _how exactly_ you grouped the terms that way? I'm trying to get to the denominators in the right side of the first step, I suppose we have to eliminate the (-1)^n in the denominator by making two separate fractions and assuming (-1)^(2n) in the first one and (-1)^(2n-1) in the second one, but I can't make it to the sum you got in your answer.

Comment: I used $\sum a_n=\sum a_{2n-1}+a_{2n}$ and $(-1)^{2n}=1,(-1)^{2n-1}=-1$.

Answer (score 1):

It diverges because $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{-1}{n\left(1+3\left(-1\right)^{n}\right)}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2\left(2n-1\right)}-\frac{1}{8n}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2n+1}{8n\left(2n-1\right)}$$ obtain $O(\frac{1}{n})$ terms.

Comment: I had the same idea!

Comment: @gimusi You did; I hadn't noticed. I made the tracking of powers of $-1$ neater, but that's about it.

Comment: It seems that I worked by odd and even indices but you worked directly on the expression! That's fine. Bye